# Statistical test for continuous predictor variable, multiple binomial response

Tags: r, logistic, binary-data

I have a dataset with hundreds of individual trees. These individuals were from seven sites that demonstrated different rates of land cover change over time (% change in area over 30 years). I'm looking to test how the rate of land cover change influences the growth trend of trees (outcomes for each individual could be positive, negative, or neutral - these are each columns in my dataset).

A reviewer suggested that logistic regression would be most appropriate for this data, but I have not been able to find a method of performing a multiple logistic regression of some sort that works for multiple binomial predictors. I could run individual logistic regressions for each outcome, however this strikes me as potentially inflating error. Does anyone have suggestions as to a test that could be used for this sort of data, or would it be best to use something like a bonferroni correction?

I'm working in R, if you have any specific suggestions for resources in the R programming environment!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that a single tree could have either a positive, neutral, or negative growth trend. So the categories are mutually exclusive. This sounds like either a multinomial logit or ordered logit. The ordered logit is a more parsimoneous model, but that parsimony comes with some strong assumptions that may not be met. You could also consider a generalized ordered logit, as a sometimes feasible middle ground between the ordered logit and multinomial logit.